# Converting an array of objects to Map Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I have an array of objects which I wish to convert into a plain Immutable map of:

```
name: {
  urlname
  id
}
```

Currently I am doing the following `data` being the array of objects:

```
data = data.map((data) => ({
  name: data.name,
  urlName: data.urlName,
  id: data.id
}))
```

What I am trying to transform is the following (`data`):

```
[{"id":"10","name":"Dave","urlName":"foo-bar","order":"-100","classId":"12","className":"David","classUrlName":"david-foo-bar"}]
```

As said above, I would like the name as the key, and both the urlName and the id as values to the key if possible. I would like to loop around data until everything is reduced to that structure if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you want to transform the data from shape to shape, you can use the [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do this job.

the `reduce` function will transform the data into a `Map` where each key is a `name`, and the values are the `id` and `urlName`

```js
const sample = [{"id":"10","name":"Dave","urlName":"foo-bar","order":"-100","classId":"12","className":"David","classUrlName":"david-foo-bar"}];

const result = sample.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return acc.set(item.name, {
     id: item.id,
     urlName: item.urlName,
   })
}, new Immutable.Map())

console.log("Dave's Id", result.getIn(["Dave", "id"]));
console.log("Date's urlName", result.getIn(["Dave", "urlName"]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.9/immutable.js"></script>
```

Check the documentation here for [ImmutableJS Reduce](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/reduce) and Native Javascript [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Both are identical in their API.

Comment: This is not a map though is it? Is this not an array of maps? When I actually just require a map

Comment: @JordanBarber you want to take the map out of the array first?

Comment: I would like it to just be a map, so just this: 

    "Dave": {
      "id": "10",
      "urlName": "foo-bar"
    }

So that I can do data.getIn(['Dave', 'url'])

Comment: @Cube3 glad to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159706/discussion-between-cube3-and-bamieh).